# How to add nifi api metrics to Prometheus target with ldap authentication?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, apache-nifi

I using nifi 1.16.3 with k8s ([this](https://github.com/cetic/helm-nifi) helm chart), in that version I can enable Nifi Reporting Task and get metrics from `/metrics` without any issues.

I tried to upgrade to version 1.20.0 in order to get also the nodes metrics (see [this PR](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/6834)), but those metrics only available in the `/nifi-api/flow/metrics/prometheus` endpoint.

I tried to add this endpoint to Prometheus:

```
- job_name: "nifi-nodes"
  static_configs:
  - targets: ["nif.mycompany.com"]
    metrics_path: '/nifi-api/flow/metrics/prometheus'
```

But I getting 401:

[image]

The Nifi is configured to work with our LDAP, I tried to add an authentication but it didn't help:

```
basic_auth:
  username: 'myusername'
  password: 'mypassword'
```

Or:

```
basic_auth_users:
  myusername: '$2b$12$bDijBmH4.B0ZSGzae3dRqe6Mwt8ZVS/43254354356346'
```

How can I make it work?

**UPDATE:**

I succeeded to create a nifi api access token and put it in this way:

```
bearer_token: mytoken
```

The issue is that the token will expired after 12 hours... so it's not good for us.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Have you checked if nifi accepts requests with basic auth `curl -u 'myusername:mypassword' http://nif.mycompany.com/nifi-api/flow/metrics/prometheus`

Comment: @markalex Thanks, you're right, I getting `Unauthorized` either. so what nifi except to get?

Comment: I'm not familiar with nifi. You'll need investigate what auth is used on nifi and pass [configure it on prometheus](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#scrape_config) (or drop auth for this path all together)

Comment: One approach I've used (with Google Cloud called [`gcp-oidc-token-proxy`](https://github.com/DazWilkin/gcp-oidc-token-proxy)) is to write a token proxy that is responsible for acquiring and refreshing access tokens. Prometheus supports limited [OAuth2](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#oauth2) and the solution sets `token_url` to the proxy which is responsible for obtaining tokens.

Comment: Thank you @DazWilkin, I just found the token it's valid only for one node so it's good enough for me 